# How can we show the video in the photogallery in titanium studio mobile app?

Tags: titanium

I have used following code to open the photo gallery. But the video is not shown by using the following code. Is there any other command to show the video in the gallery?

```
  Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery({
        success : function(event) {
             uplaodideo(event.media);
            },
        cancel : function(e) {
             alert(e);
        },
        error : function(err) {
             Ti.API.error(err);
        },
        mediaTypes : [Titanium.Media.VIDEO_MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO]
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide more details, like Android or iOS, which SDK you are using etc

Comment: I am using Android sdk...

Answer (score 0):

I hope following links may help you. The code you have suggested only works on iOS.
Here in android a simple idea is to use, intents. For more info on intents please visit the second link, feel free to connect me if you have any doubts.

[Developer Appcelerator Q&A](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/19181/video-gallery)

[Titanium.Android.Intent](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Intent)